# Does Inline integration override the chosen "standard" integration algorithm?

Tags: solver, dymola

In Dymola framework, the "Simulation" section allow you to specify the parameters of the Simulation.

Among all the possible settings, there the following two:

1. Under "General" Tab, you can specify the integration algorithm (e.g. Euler)
2. Under "RealTime" Tab, you can specify additionally an Inline integration algorithm (e.g.Implicit Euler)

I am familiar with the concept of Inline integration and I known it can be suitable to speed up fixed step simulations. However I wonder why it is possible to select BOTH of the algorithms in 1) and 2) above, for the same simulation. Shouldn't the inline integration (when set) override the "classical" integration? Or somehow both of the algorithms selected are used in the the same simulation, but at different stages?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simply that no easier to use way of setting both has been found (yet).

Note that specifying inline integration automatically switches the main simulation algorithm to "Euler" (since some versions).

Comment: Thanks, are you aware of any documentation that supports your statement?